# get the MovieRecommendation throw exception

Tags: spring, jsp, neo4j, spring-data, spring-data-neo4j

i use spring data neo4j to work,i have a repository to recommend movie,i think cypher have not problem,and i can get the  recommendation,but i can not get the value of Movie.title and rating ,why it shows movie id not property to the recommendation.class,in my log and error info you can see,why ? 
i have severl similar problems,it seems cant get the value in jsp?help me thank you very much .heart man
recommendation.class

```
package com.oberon.fm.domain;
import org.springframework.data.neo4j.annotation.QueryResult;
@QueryResult
public class MovieRecommendation {

Movie movie;
int rating;
```

the repository

```
@Query("match (user:User {login: {0}})-[r:RATED]->(movie)<-[r2:RATED]-(other)-[r3:RATED]->(otherMovie) "
        + " where r.stars >= 3 and r2.stars >= r.stars and r3.stars >= r.stars "
        + " with otherMovie, avg(r3.stars) as rating, count(*) as cnt" 
        + " order by rating desc, cnt desc"
        + " return otherMovie limit 10")
List<MovieRecommendation> getRecommendations(String login);
```

my controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/user", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String profile(Model model, HttpServletRequest request) {
    // User user=populator.getUserFromSession();

    HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);
    User user = (User) session.getAttribute("user");
    model.addAttribute("user", user);
    if (user != null) {
        List<MovieRecommendation> mr = movieRepository.getRecommendations(user.getLogin());
        model.addAttribute("recommendations", mr);
    }
    return "user/index";
}
```

index.jsp

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="fn" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" %>
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<%--@elvariable id="user" type="com.oberon.fm.domain.User"--%>
<%--@elvariable id="recommendations"type="java.util.List<com.oberon.fm.domain.MovieRecommendation>"--%>
<%--@elvariable id="recommendation"type="com.oberon.fm.domain.MovieRecommendation"--%>
<html>
<head>
<title>Profile</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/Web/css/style.css"/>

</head>
<body>
 <div class="span-third">
      <h2>Your recommendations</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="span-third last">
      <h2>${fn:length(recommendations)}</h2>
    </div>
      <ul class="rated-movies-list span-all last">
          <c:choose>
              <c:when test="${not empty recommendations}">
                  <c:forEach items="${recommendations}" var="recommendation">
                      <c:set var="movie" value="${recommendation.movie}"/>
                      <c:set var="stars" value="${recommendation.rating}"/>
                      <li>
                          <h4> <a href="<c:url value="/movies/${movie.id}" />"><c:out value="${movie.title}"/>
                              (${movie.year}) - &quot;${movie.tagline}&quot;</a>

                          <img class="rating" alt="${stars} stars" src="<c:url value="/images/rated_${stars}.png" />"/>
                          </h4>
                      </li>
                  </c:forEach>
              </c:when>
              <c:otherwise>
                  There are no recommendations for you, perhaps you have to add some friends?
              </c:otherwise>
          </c:choose>
      </ul>
    <div class="break"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

i can get the length of recommendation
log and error info

```
16:19:32.403 [http-nio-8080-exec-8] DEBUG  o.s.w.b.a.s.HandlerMethodInvoker - Invoking request handler method: publicjava.lang.String  com.oberon.fm.controller.UserController.profile(org.springframework.ui.Model, javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)
16:19:32.403 [http-nio-8080-exec-8] DEBUG o.s.t.jta.JtaTransactionManager - Creating new transaction with name [null]: PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,ISOLATION_DEFAULT
16:19:32.404 [http-nio-8080-exec-8] DEBUG o.s.d.n.s.q.CypherQueryEngineImpl - Executing cypher query: match (user:User {login: {0}})-[r:RATED]->(movie)<-[r2:RATED]-(other)-[r3:RATED]->(otherMovie)  where r.stars >= 3 and r2.stars >= r.stars and r3.stars >= r.stars  with otherMovie, avg(r3.stars) as rating, count(*) as cnt order by rating desc, cnt desc return otherMovie limit 10 params {0=micha}
16:19:32.739 [http-nio-8080-exec-8] DEBUG o.s.t.jta.JtaTransactionManager - Initiating transaction commit
16:19:32.740 [http-nio-8080-exec-8] DEBUG c.o.fm.controller.UserController - ()()()()()()()()()()()[com.oberon.fm.domain.MovieRecommendation@bc5162, com.oberon.fm.domain.MovieRecommendation@1b8ceab]
16:19:32.740 [http-nio-8080-exec-8] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Invoking afterPropertiesSet() on bean with name 'user/index'
16:19:32.740 [http-nio-8080-exec-8] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.transaction.config.internalTransactionAdvisor'
16:19:32.740 [http-nio-8080-exec-8] DEBUG o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Rendering view [org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView: name 'user/index'; URL [/pages/user/index.jsp]] in DispatcherServlet with name 'context'
16:19:32.740 [http-nio-8080-exec-8] DEBUG o.s.web.servlet.view.JstlView - Added model object 'user' of type [com.oberon.fm.domain.User] to request in view with name 'user/index'
16:19:32.740 [http-nio-8080-exec-8] DEBUG o.s.web.servlet.view.JstlView - Added model object 'recommendations' of type [java.util.ArrayList] to request in view with name 'user/index'
16:19:32.740 [http-nio-8080-exec-8] DEBUG o.s.web.servlet.view.JstlView - Added model object 'org.springframework.validation.BindingResult.user' of type [org.springframework.validation.BeanPropertyBindingResult] to request in view with name 'user/index'
16:19:32.740 [http-nio-8080-exec-8] DEBUG o.s.web.servlet.view.JstlView - Forwarding to resource [/pages/user/index.jsp] in InternalResourceView 'user/index'
16:19:33.838 [http-nio-8080-exec-8] DEBUG o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Error rendering view [org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView: name 'user/index'; URL [/pages/user/index.jsp]] in DispatcherServlet with name 'context'
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page /pages/user/index.jsp at line 86

83:               <c:choose>
84:                   <c:when test="${not empty recommendations}">
85:                       <c:forEach items="${recommendations}"  var="recommendation">
86:                           <c:set var="movie" value="${recommendation.movie}"/>
87:                           <c:set var="stars" value="${recommendation.rating}"/>
88:                           <li>
89:                               <h4> <a href="<c:url value="/movies/${movie.id}" />"><c:out value="${movie.title}"/>:
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:568) ~[jasper.jar:8.0.15]
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:470) ~[jasper.jar:8.0.15]
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:396) ~[jasper.jar:8.0.15]
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:340) ~[jasper.jar:8.0.15]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725) [servlet-api.jar:na]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291) [catalina.jar:8.0.15]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) [catalina.jar:8.0.15]
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) [tomcat-websocket.jar:8.0.15]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239) [catalina.jar:8.0.15]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) [catalina.jar:8.0.15]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:721) ~[catalina.jar:8.0.15]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:466) ~[catalina.jar:8.0.15]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:391) ~[catalina.jar:8.0.15]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:318) ~[catalina.jar:8.0.15]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:168) ~[spring-webmvc-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:303) ~[spring-webmvc-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1228) [spring-webmvc-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1011) [spring-webmvc-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:955) [spring-webmvc-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:877) [spring-webmvc-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:966) [spring-webmvc-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:857) [spring-webmvc-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:618) [servlet-api.jar:na]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:842) [spring-webmvc-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725) [servlet-api.jar:na]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291) [catalina.jar:8.0.15]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) [catalina.jar:8.0.15]
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) [tomcat-websocket.jar:8.0.15]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239) [catalina.jar:8.0.15]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) [catalina.jar:8.0.15]
at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88) [spring-web-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239) [catalina.jar:8.0.15]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) [catalina.jar:8.0.15]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219) [catalina.jar:8.0.15]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106) [catalina.jar:8.0.15]
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501) [catalina.jar:8.0.15]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142) [catalina.jar:8.0.15]
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79) [catalina.jar:8.0.15]
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:610) [catalina.jar:8.0.15]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88) [catalina.jar:8.0.15]
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:537) [catalina.jar:8.0.15]
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1085) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.0.15]
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:658) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.0.15]
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:222) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.0.15]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1556) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.0.15]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1513) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.0.15]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_05]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_05]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-util.jar:8.0.15]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_05]
Caused by: org.apache.jasper.el.JspPropertyNotFoundException: /pages/user/index.jsp(86,26) '${recommendation.movie}' Property 'movie' not found on type com.oberon.fm.domain.MovieRecommendation
at org.apache.jasper.el.JspValueExpression.getValue(JspValueExpression.java:120) ~[jasper.jar:8.0.15]
at org.apache.jsp.pages.user.index_jsp._jspx_meth_c_005fset_005f3(index_jsp.java:879) ~[na:na]
at org.apache.jsp.pages.user.index_jsp._jspx_meth_c_005fforEach_005f2(index_jsp.java:818) ~[na:na]
at org.apache.jsp.pages.user.index_jsp._jspx_meth_c_005fwhen_005f2(index_jsp.java:782) ~[na:na]
at org.apache.jsp.pages.user.index_jsp._jspx_meth_c_005fchoose_005f2(index_jsp.java:746) ~[na:na]
at org.apache.jsp.pages.user.index_jsp._jspService(index_jsp.java:171) ~[na:na]
at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70) ~[jasper.jar:8.0.15]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725) [servlet-api.jar:na]
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432) ~[jasper.jar:8.0.15]
... 49 common frames omitted
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to have getters for jsp el expressions, it won't recognize public properties.

Change your `MovieRecommendation` class (and possibly others) to something like this:

```
@QueryResult
public class MovieRecommendation {

    Movie movie;
    int rating;

    Movie getMovie() { .... }
    int getRating() {....}
```

Comment: oh.stupid me .it work.but do you konw why i can not get the value of movie.title .you can see the values in jsp i can not get all

Comment: Do you get a different exception now?

Comment: no i t donest a jsp problem.i throw cypher get 2 recommendation is null.do you know why

Comment: I don't understand what problem you are having now. Has the exception in jsp disappeared? If so you should mark this as resolved and ask a new question with proper description.